# Any CANopen adapters supported on the PI?

Tags: usb, linux

Does anyone know if there are any CANopen protocol converters supported on the Pi, or if ones that work under Linux could be ported to it?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to start a bounty for this question. This is not exactly about "easy and well known stuff", even if it's an interesting question...

Comment: Long time no answer...I am confused, is there any reason why some USB to CAN adapter should not work? Of course, if Linux drivers were available, like for example this one: [http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm](http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/index.htm) The drivers are LGPL, so adaptation should be possible. It is stated they supported CANFestival, so that should be it. Did you find some adapter with the same functionality, and proven to work with CANOpen?